# Create JSON object from multiple row input fields using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

The multiple row input fields are

[image]

Using jQuery I created a method to derive JSON

```
function createReminderJSON() {
         jsonObj = [];
        $("input[class=occasion]").each(function() {

            var occasion = $(this).val();

            if ('' !== occasion) {
                var fname = $('.fname').val();
                var lname = $('.lname').val();

                item = {}
                item["occasion"] = occasion;
                item["firstName"] = fname;
                item["lastName"] = lname;

                jsonObj.push(item);
            }

        });
        console.log(jsonObj);
        $.ajax({
            type : "post",
            contentType : "application/json",
            url : "/add/reminder",
            data : JSON.stringify(jsonObj)
        }); 
    }
```

JSON created is

```
[{occasion:1,firstName:Tim,lastName:Cook},{occasion:1,firstName:Steve,lastName:Jobs}]
```

HTML of input fields:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="occasion" placeholder="occasion" class="occasion" ng-model="rem.occasion"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="fname" class="fname" ng-model="rem.firstName"/><td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="lname" class="lname" ng-model="rem.lastName"/><td>
</tr>
```

Angular JS method invoked on `ng-click=addReminder()` is

```
function Reminder($scope,$http){
        $scope.addReminder = function() {
            var reminders = $scope.rem;
            alert(reminders);
            $http.post('/add/reminder', reminders).success(function(data) {
                alert("Success!");
            });
        }
    }
```

Is angular.forEach necessary? How can I create JSON using Angular JS silmilar to the jQuery one. The alert is giving me `undefined` when I tried with a single row input.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of the question? http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to declare an empty object in the controller.

```
$scope.rem = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not. Remember that JSON stands for Javascript Object Notation. It is the way an object is being described. So the models in your AngularJS controller - as soon as they are serialized 'over the wire' by a POST for example, look like the JSON you want.

Here's a Fiddle that demonstrates: http://jsfiddle.net/358uqccy/3/. The `| json` filter converts an object into JSON to show you that the JSON of your model is available at all times.

Comment: Hi Spike, I can see the JSON using console.log() and the filter you specified also works fine. The problem is that '$scope.rem' doesn't have the JSON required.

Comment: What does it have? Are you talking about the quotes around the names?

Comment: @Kni8 - I would set things up a bit differntly than you have. Here's how I would do it: http://jsfiddle.net/358uqccy/5/ . I hope it's close enough to what you had so it can actually help you.